# cant overcome this org.springframework.dao.dataaccessexception

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am learning Spring boot and am doing a project with jdbcTemplate performing CRUD operations.
Whenever, I introduce the getObject() parameters in my query the exception shows up. The IDE suggests to add exception or to surround with try catch; both of which lead to an error

```
"Incompatible types 
Expected: java.lang.throwable 
Found:org.springframework.dao.dataaccessexception"
```

This is my service method:

```
import com.vaidiksanatansewa.gurusewa.model.Appointment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import java.util.List;

public class AppointmentService {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


   public void add(Appointment appointment) throws DataAccessException {
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into appointment(name, address, contact,
 sewa_fid, guru_fid,date,
 hour , status, created_date, updated_date) 
 values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
 appointment.getName(),appointment.getAddress(),appointment.getPhone(),
 appointment.getSewa_fid(),appointment.getGuru_fid(),
 appointment.getDate(), appointment.getHour(),appointment.getStatus(),
 appointment.getCreated_date(),appointment.getUpdated_date());
```

}

```
        }
```

Heres the model:

```
package com.vaidiksanatansewa.gurusewa.model;

import java.util.Date;


public class Appointment {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String address;
    String phone;
    Integer sewa_fid;
    Integer guru_fid;
    Date date;
    Integer hour;
    Integer status;
    Date created_date;
    Date updated_date;

    public Appointment() {
    }

    public Appointment(Long id, String name, String address, String phone, Integer sewa_fid, Integer guru_fid, Date date, Integer hour, Integer status, Date created_date, Date updated_date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.sewa_fid = sewa_fid;
        this.guru_fid = guru_fid;
        this.date = date;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.status = status;
        this.created_date = created_date;
        this.updated_date = updated_date;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Integer getSewa_fid() {
        return sewa_fid;
    }

    public void setSewa_fid(Integer sewa_fid) {
        this.sewa_fid = sewa_fid;
    }

    public Integer getGuru_fid() {
        return guru_fid;
    }

    public void setGuru_fid(Integer guru_fid) {
        this.guru_fid = guru_fid;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Integer getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(Integer hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getCreated_date() {
        return created_date;
    }

    public void setCreated_date(Date created_date) {
        this.created_date = created_date;
    }

    public Date getUpdated_date() {
        return updated_date;
    }

    public void setUpdated_date(Date updated_date) {
        this.updated_date = updated_date;
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
package com.vaidiksanatansewa.gurusewa.controller;

import com.vaidiksanatansewa.gurusewa.model.Appointment;
import com.vaidiksanatansewa.gurusewa.service.AppointmentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

    @RestController
    public class AppointmentController {

        @Autowired
        AppointmentService appointmentService;

        @RequestMapping("/Appointment")
        public List<Appointment> getAll() {

            return appointmentService.getAll();
        }

        @RequestMapping("/Appointment/{id}")
        public Appointment getById(@PathVariable Long id) {

            return appointmentService.getById(id);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value= "/student")
        public void add(@RequestBody Appointment Appointment)  {
            appointmentService.add(Appointment);

        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value= "/student/{id}")
        public void markAsAccepted(@RequestBody Appointment Appointment,@PathVariable Long id){
            appointmentService.markAsAccepted(id,Appointment);
        }



   }
```

What would be the cause of it? Could anyone shed a light upon this??

Comment: If you remove `throws DataAccessException` from the method what error do you get?

Comment: "Unhandled Exception: org.springframework.dao.dataAccessException"
I simply get this error upon removing the throws DataAccessException

Comment: Why @Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; ? You can simply create an object like private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Comment: Don't you need to `catch` or `throw` this exception in the `controller` level?

Comment: do you have `spring.datasource.*` in configuration files?

Comment: @htshame As I mentioned if I introduce the exception in controller level or in service level Im getting this error   "Incompatible types 
Expected: java.lang.throwable 
Found:org.springframework.dao.dataaccessexception"

Comment: @NiVeR I don't have any such configuration file.

Comment: how do you instruct spring which database to use?

Comment: @NiVeR have an application.properties file in resources folder spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/vaidik_sewa
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=kush
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 1):

The error is strange, it might be some project ill-state. Try to build the project (maven build or install) and verifiy that the error is still present ( and it is the same) in the compiled war.